# Error executing EntityManageer delete native query with in clause parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I get an error executing EntityManageer delete native query with in clause parameter. The parameter is of type List and I want to do something like-

```
List<UUID> ids = ...
entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN (:ids)")
        .setParameter("ids", ids)
        .executeUpdate();
```

The exception that I get is-

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: IN could not convert type bytea to uuid
  Position: 39
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:108)
[snip]
```

Please let me know how I can run the delete query above.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a Native query you should have something like below:       `entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN (?1)")
        .setParameter(1, ids)
        .executeUpdate();`

Also, I think you don't need native query in this case, below code should work too:

```
entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN (:ids)")
    .setParameter("ids", ids)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: In Native query make sure its a SQL table name for FOO.

Comment: I think the error I get is specific to postgres and hibernate. I'll try updating the question later.